# Problems with MATLAB conditional logic

Tags: matlab, if-statement

If you input any number more than 20 it works perfectly, but if you input a number greater than 20 the output looks something along the lines of

> > yes he willYeah hes gonna piss himself

I just want it to display

> > yes he will

Why is it still outputting a fragment of an entirely different if statement. If the number inputted is greater than 20 then i want the program to just end there.

```
fprintf('Let''s see if Dane will piss himself...');
x = input('\n\n\nHow many drinks has Dane consumed? ');
if x >= 20;
    fprintf('Yes he will');
elseif x < 20;
    drugs = input('\n\nHas Dane done molly or shrooms? ','s');
end
answer = strcmp(drugs,'yes');
answer1 = strcmp(drugs,'no');
if (answer);
    disp('Yeah he''s gonna piss himself');
elseif (answer1);
    disp('Probably not but you should still sleep in the quad');
end
```

Comment: Do you think you could pick more professional examples for your future questions please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the part of the code that currently is after the first `end` should be moved before that `end`:

```
fprintf('Let''s see if Dane will piss himself...');
x = input('\n\n\nHow many drinks has Dane consumed? ');
if x >= 20;
    fprintf('Yes he will');
elseif x < 20;
    drugs = input('\n\nHas Dane done molly or shrooms? ','s');
    answer = strcmp(drugs,'yes');
    answer1 = strcmp(drugs,'no');
    if (answer);
        disp('Yeah he''s gonna piss himself');
    elseif (answer1);
        disp('Probably not but you should still sleep in the quad');
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see when I pass *28* as the input:

```
How many drinks has Dane consumed? 28
Yes he will??? Undefined function or variable 'drugs'.

Error in ==> tst at 8
answer = strcmp(drugs,'yes');
```

Anyway, if you "want the program to just end there" you can put a `return` afterward. 
 like this:

```
if x >= 20;
    fprintf('Yes he will');
    return
elseif x < 20;
    drugs = input('\n\nHas Dane done molly or shrooms? ','s');
end
```